# Python: How to replace values in array by NaNs?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix

```
f=numpy.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[7,8,9]])
>>> f
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

I want to replace values in the first row by NaNs. How can I do it? I tried

```
f[0:1]=numpy.nan(3)
```

and it does not work, though

```
f[0:1]=numpy.zeros(3)
```

works just fine. What can I do about it?

Comment: If your question is python-version-specific, feel free to add a version tag back to it. If it's not, then the generic tag is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer type does not allow `nan` in `numpy`.

This would work:

```
import numpy as np

f = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [2,3,4],
              [7,8,9]], dtype=float)

f[0, :] = np.nan

# [[ nan  nan  nan]
#  [  2.   3.   4.]
#  [  7.   8.   9.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Do this:**

```
import numpy

f = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[7,8,9]])
f = f.astype(float)
#Put nan in the first row of the matrix f
f[0,] = numpy.nan
```

---

**Results**

```
print(f)

array([[nan, nan, nan],
       [ 2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]])
```

---

**More details**

When you typed:

```
numpy.nan(3)
```

You probably got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

This is because the `numpy.nan` is called without any arguments.